# Create a relationship as common in nspredicate

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nspredicate

The below predicate is worked for me.

```
NSPredicate *predicate   = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mcu.family LIKE \"STM32\" AND mcu.serie IN {\"STM32F3\"}"];
```

How to assign the mcu relationship as common to whole attribute.As like as below,

```
NSPredicate *predicate   = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((family LIKE \"STM32\") AND (serie IN {\"STM32F3\"})) _ mcu"];
```

What can I assign the key in a underscore(_) Place?

Kindly help me.

Comment: Looking throughout the [NSPredicate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBNF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001796-CJBDBHCB) I can't as an `AS` statement. Is MCU an entity?

Comment: Hi Flexicoder, yes,MCU is an entity. Kindly give any ideas.Which key i need to put in a AS statement place?

Comment: Surely then setting the Entity in the `NSFetchRequest` makes it common?

Comment: yes.I have the nsfetchrequest in DataManager

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Could you post the block of code that does the fetch and uses the predicate

Comment: If the first predicate works, what's the problem?